# angular2-datatable dependency issue during rollup to make bundle file

Tags: angular, dependencies

I am making an application in angular 2 and when performing AOT Compilation as mentioned in Angular Documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html steps, i am getting following error :

> Error : 'DataTableModule' is not exported by node_modules/angular2-datatable/index.js

Here is my code :

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory';
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DataTableModule } from "angular2-datatable";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from     '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import { IndexComponent } from './index.component';
import { RegisterationFormComponent } from "./registration/registeration-form.component";
import { StaffListingComponent } from './company/staff-listing.component';
import {TranslateModule} from 'ng2-translate';

@NgModule({

imports:      [ BrowserModule,DataTableModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', component: IndexComponent},
        { path: 'my-staff', component: StaffListingComponent},

  ], { useHash: true })],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, IndexComponent, StaffListingComponent,   DataFilterPipe ],
  providers: [AuthenticationService],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
 })

 export class AppModule { }
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
   System.config({
   paths: {
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles 
  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
  'ng2-translate':'npm:ng2-translate',
   'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
   'angular2-datatable': 'npm:angular2-datatable',
   'angular2-infinite-scroll':'npm:angular2-infinite-scroll',
  },
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'ng2-translate': {
      main:'./bundles/ng2-translate.umd.js', 
      defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'lodash': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-datatable': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-infinite-scroll': {
      main:'./angular2-infinite-scroll.js', 
      defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
});
```

rollup-config.js

```
import rollup      from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

export default {
 entry: 'app/main.js',
 dest: 'dist/build.js', // output a single application bundle
 sourceMap: false,
 format: 'iife',
plugins: [
  nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
  commonjs({
    include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
  }),
  uglify()
 ]
}
```

angular2-database dependency is working fine without AOT Compilation. But giving error while rollup. Can anyone please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by making following changes in rollup-config.js file

rollup-config.js

```
import rollup      from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

export default {
   entry: 'app/main.js',
   dest: 'dist/build.js', // output a single application bundle
   sourceMap: false,
   format: 'iife',
   plugins: [
      nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
      commonjs({
    include: ['node_modules/rxjs/**','node_modules/angular2-datatable/**','node_modules/lodash/**'],
    }),
     uglify()
   ]
 }
```